# Ingress traffic shaping with OVS port

Tags: tc, traffic-shaping, openvswitch

I have a ovs topology like this:

```
       h1
        |
        |
    [SW 1]
    /     \
   /       \
[SW 2]  [SW 3]
   \       /
    \     /
    [SW 4]
        |
        |
       h2
```

Traffic is sent from h1 to h2.
I want do this thing: in normal traffic will go in path: sw1 -> sw2 -> sw4. But, if traffic rate is more than 300kbit/s, rate exceeded traffic will go through path sw1 -> sw3 -> sw4. I  know ovs egress policy will drop rate exceeded traffic, so i tried use tc filter with mirred action:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev s1-eth1 handle ffff: ingress
sudo tc filter add dev s1-eth1 parent ffff: protocol ip u32 /
                                   match ip src 10.0.0.1/32 /                    
  action police rate 300kbit burst 100k conform-exceed pipe /         
                  action mirred egress redirect dev s1-eth2 /
```

with s1-eth1 and s1-eth2 is ports connect s1 with s2 and s3. But it doesn't work.
So, can anybody help me to do this?